# "A decreases with B"

Tags: grammar

I encountered today in a text this sentence:

> We found a decline in colonization with isolation.

Does it means that colonization declines when isolation increases? Or when it decreases?

Comment: The normal interpretation would be that increased isolation correlates with a decline in colonization.

Comment: Out of context, you can't tell whether _colonization with isolation_ is a single noun phrase representing a datum that increased, or whether there are two data, _colonization_ and _isolation_, which may be correlated or not. One sentence is seldom enough.

Comment: @JohnLawler here is the context https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2022-5 the sentence in the abstract. they are 2 data, and he is trying to determine the relationship between colonization and isolation, among other things

Comment: tl;dr. I would have the same interpretation as @HotLicks. Isolation and colonization are inversely correlated.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, theres no way of knowing whats meant.  It could be a petri dish and its referring to bacteria colonization that was isolated by a specific difference within it.  In which case its not really saying, "as isolation increases, colonization decreases" rather there was a decline in colonization in our isolated group.

Comment: here is the context nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2022-5 the sentence in the abstract. they are 2 data, and he is trying to determine the relationship between colonization and isolation, among other things

Comment: @Mostafa Taha Unless usage has changed remarkably in recent years, 'they are 2 data' is unidiomatic. I'd expect ' ... two _sets of_ data ...'.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is derived from the contributions of John Lawler, in raising the need for context for the question, and Mostafa Taha, in providing it.  So I take no credit for this answer.

The context allows us to see that this is ornithological research, setting out to establish the effect on bird populations of area (how much room there is on an island) and isolation (how easy it is to get to and leave).

> Here we address both deficiencies to reveal, for island birds, the empirical shape of the general relationships that determine how colonization, extinction and speciation rates co-vary with the area and isolation of islands.

The word *co-vary* reflect the question whether, for example, the more isolated an island is, (a) the more species become extinct, or (b) the fewer species become extinct.

In case (c), the conclusion with be that they do not co-vary.  The degree of isolation does not effect the rate of species extinction at all.

In cases (a) and (b), they do co-vary, in (a) positively, in (b) inversely

The paper concludes:

> **We found a decline in colonization with isolation**, a decline in extinction with area and an increase in speciation with area and isolation

I have to say that the this sentence is not clearly written.  A knowledge of language alone will not permit an answer.  Only scientific common sense, albeit of an elementary nature allows a definite interpretation.  It could mean that **the two decline together**, or it could involve ellipse and mean that colonisation declines with  isolation.  In fact, common sense dictates that it must be so.  The further away an island is from other islands or the mainland, the harder it is going to be for would-be avian colonists to reach it.  So they vary **inversely**.  Similarly, common sense rather than the English language dictates that "with area" must again indicate an inverse co-variance: the greater the area of the island, the more room there is for all the existing species to survive.  I suspect, though the English doesn't show it, that the speciation increased in direct **(not inverse)** proportion with area (more room = less competition/more diversity of living conditions), and with islolation (less threat of immigrant predators).

So I am afraid the editor of **Nature** missed an important fault of clarity.  The lesson is that when writing about co-variance or correlation, it is essential to qualify the items co-vary positively (both go up - or down - together) or inversely (one goes up while the other goes down).