# How to convey a relation between a parameter and two things that it controls in opposite directions?

Tags: phrase-requests, software

In writing the user manual for a piece of software, I'm trying to communicate the relationship between a numerical control, which I'll call frob, and two properties, which I'll call foo and bar.

Currently I have something to the effect of:

> When frob is set to zero, foo and bar are unaffected by step. As frob is increased, foo increases, and bar decreases; as frob is decreased, foo decreases and bar increases.

Is there a more concise and easier to parse way to communicate this relationship to a non-technical audience?

Comment: Define *step*. Are you trying to say that foo and bar are inversely related as a function of frob?

Comment: I think we need to know what the actual meanings of *frob,* *foo,* *bar,* and *step* are.

Comment: You could look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/526360/a-decreases-with-b

Comment: In mathematics we would often just say that "_foo_ is an increasing function of _frob_ and _bar_ is a decreasing function of _frob_". The inverse relationship between _foo_ and _bar_ is then implied.

Comment: You could use something like "vice versa when it's decreased".

Comment: But it's not clear that you really need to second clause -- any reasonable person would assume that the opposite happens when you reverse the knob direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

When frob is set to zero, foo and bar are unaffected by step. As frob increases or decreases, foo does the same while bar does the opposite.